# Make a JDialog stick or snap to another one when moving it close to it

Tags: java, user-interface, jdialog

I'm trying to reproduce a feature I've seen on several apps:
I have a GUI app with several JDialogs.
I'd like to easily organize them tightly on screen:
when I move one JDialog, and one of its borders gets "close" (within 5 pixels for example) to another JDialog, I'd like it to automatically snap and stick right along it.

any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a ComponentListener to the dialog and listen for the comopnentMoved() event.

You can use the Window.getWindows() method to get all the Windows. Then you loop through the Windows and get the bounds of each window. Whenever you are near a window you manually set the size of the window you are moving.

Of course you will also need to handle the situation when you want to move the window away from another window so maybe you need to start a Timer with every componentMoved event and only manually position the window after events have stopped being generated.

Comment: it's the idea. several things that I had to solve: beware of windows set as not visible, if you have a lot of small windows be careful to well identify the two windows that should "interact"...